# Dart 2D List - add() adds temp element to List but initialises the previous element to null when the temp element is cleared

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this function that works with `List`:

```
List<List<String>> experience() async {

  List<List<String>> totalExperience = [];
  List<String> temp = []; //a temporary List

  temp = ["a", "b"];
  totalExperience.add(temp); //adding the temp List to the 2D List
  print(totalExperience);
  //here I intend to remove the 2 elements ("a", "b") from the temp List,
  //so that it can be used again.
  temp.clear(); 

  temp = ["c", "d"]; //initialising the temp List with 2 new elements
  totalExperience.add(temp);
  print(totalExperience);
  temp.clear();

  temp = ["e", "f"];
  totalExperience.add(temp);
  print(totalExperience);

  return totalExperience;
}
```

This is actual the output in the console:

```
[[a, b]]
[[], [c, d]]
[[], [], [e, f]]
```

As clear from the output, the previous 2 elements in the `totalExperience` List got removed.

However, I expected the output of this code to be something like this:

```
[[a, b], [c, d], [e, f]]
```

I can not figure out what could be the possible error in this code.

Also I might have framed the question title wrong. Will update it as soon as I figure out the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time clear your temp array which reference actually you added to your totalExperience array. That's why whenever you clear temp array and then clear also in reference which add in totalExperience array. You can just copy your temp when adding to the totalExperience array.

```
List<List<String>> experience()  {
    
      List<List<String>> totalExperience = [];
      List<String> temp = []; //a temporary List
      List<String> tempOrgi;
      temp = ["a", "b"];
     
      totalExperience.add([...temp]); //adding the temp List to the 2D List
      print(totalExperience);
      //here I intend to remove the 2 elements ("a", "b") from the temp List,
      //so that it can be used again.
      temp.clear(); 
    
      temp = ["c", "d"]; //initialising the temp List with 2 new elements
      totalExperience.add([...temp]);
      print(totalExperience);
      temp.clear();
    
      temp = ["e", "f"];
      totalExperience.add([...temp]);
      print(totalExperience);
    
      return totalExperience;
    }
```

Comment: `[...temp]` what does this actually mean?

Comment: [...temp] This clone actual temp array and add to the totalExperience array.

Comment: this is like copy that I said, and every time a new list added

Answer (score 1):

Every time you clear the temp list, it clear's temp reference too, so a list that added to totalExperience clear too.
Use different temp lists every time or first copy list then add copy list.

You can do like this :

```
Future<List<List<String>>> experience() async {

  List<List<String>> totalExperience = [];

  totalExperience.add(["a", "b"]); //adding the temp List to the 2D List
  print(totalExperience);


  totalExperience.add(["c", "d"]);
  print(totalExperience);

  totalExperience.add(["e", "f"]);
  print(totalExperience);

  return totalExperience;
}
```

Comment: This solutions works, but this is not what I wanted to know. Do you mean something like pointers in C++?